# Microsoft ml.net Concatenate 2 columns as a label

Tags: c#, machine-learning, ml.net

I've been wondering if it was possible to concatenate 2 columns of the datatype string into the label column.

What I tried was:

```
        pipeline.Add(new ColumnConcatenator("Label", "string1", "string2"));
```

But that just spits out a V2(text, 2). And a Label must be of type R4-R8.

The reason I need this is because I only have 2 input variables and I want to use regression to determine which is the best.

Thanks !

Comment: Regression operates on numeric datatypes, trying to fit a function to the data. Are your strings categoricals, do you need to convert them to numbers through something like CategoricalOneHot?  Can you describe your problem in more detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ColumnConcatenator is currently taking your two columns and producing a new vector typed column of width two. It's taking `a` and `b` and up-converting to a vector `[a, b]`.

I think you're asking how to produce a new Label equal to `a + b` where `a` & `b` are strings. Eg: `var a = "Hello"; var b = "World"; var c = a + c; // c is HelloWorld`.

There is no way currently in ML.NET to accomplish the second method (normal string concat). You may want to combine your strings before the ML.NET code. It's something we'll look into for future versions of ML.NET, and you're invited to submit an issue requesting it: https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/new.

---

**Update:**

We have added the expression transform which can be used to concatenate strings (among many other things).

Usage:

```
pipeline.Append(ML.Transforms.Expression("Label", "(x, y) : concat(x, \"-\", y)", "LabelColOne", "LabelColTwo"))
```

For input of LabelColOne=`"Cat"` and LabelColTwo=`"Dog"`, it join them together with a "-" to produce Label=`"Cat-Dog"`.

Comment: You are correct, I'll submit an issue, thanks for the reply!